# Using Pointer on 2D Array to Function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm very new to programming so I'm sorry if this will sound as a bad question.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Order(int *waiterList){

    printf("Number is %d", *waiterList[0][1]);

}

int main(){

    int waiterList[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    Order(&waiterList);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is giving me this error:

```
pointer.c: In function 'Order':
pointer.c:5:39: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
printf("Number is %d", *waiterList[0][1]);

pointer.c: In function '`enter code here`main':
pointer.c:13:8: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Order' from incompatible pointer type [- 
Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  Order(&waiterList);

pointer.c:3:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int (*)[3][3]'
void Order(int *waiterList){
```

Sorry I've never used array before but our final project is requiring us to use array and I'm finding it difficult to understand the articles I found on google... Hope you could help a student out, It's also my first time posting here because I'm kinda desperate.

Comment: Surprise: `&waiterList` is not an `int *`.

Comment: Do you know how I could fix this? I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3911400)

Comment: It's simple: `void Order(int waiterList[3][3])`. You need not even worry about "array decay", that part is silently and implicitly handled by the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to achieve this would be

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Order(int waiterList[3][3]){  // receive an array of type `int [3][3]`
    printf("Number is %d", waiterList[0][1]);

}

int main(){

    int waiterList[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    Order(waiterList);  // just pass the array name

    return 0;
}
```

If you **must** use pointers, use proper types:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Order(int (*waiterList)[3][3]){   // pointer to an array of type `int[3][3]`

    printf("Number is %d", (*waiterList)[0][1]);

}

int main(){

    int waiterList[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    Order(&waiterList);  // pass the address of the array

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays *decay* to a pointer to its first element, for a generic array `a` it decays to `&a[0]`.

In the case of an arrays like your `waiterList` in the `main` function, when it decays to a pointer to its first element (`&waiterList[0]`) it will have the type "pointer to an array". More specifically for `waiterList` the type becomes `int (*)[3]`. Which has to be the type of the argument for the `Order` function:

```
void Order(int (*waiterList)[3]){
    printf("Number is %d", waiterList[0][1]);
}
```

You call it simply passing the array as any other variable, no pointer or address-of operator needed:

```
Order(waiterList);
```

Comment: Did you mean `(*waiterList)[0][1]`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, as `waiterList` is a pointer then `waiterList[0]` dereferences the pointer already (remember it's equal to `*(waiterList + 0)`). That dereference will give an array which is then indexed the "normal" way.

Comment: @SouravGhosh No it's correct, he doesn't use a pointer to array with two dimensions as in your example. But of course there's no need to use array pointer syntax at all here. `int waiterList[3][3]` is the most readable parameter declaration.